# Could A28A transistor work for controlling Rx/Tx pin?

Tags: transistors, pnp

I want to control a robot with my arduino via RX/TX.
Here is the wiring:[image: wiring]

They recommend transistor pnp **2N4403.**

Another guy said that a small signal, low power PNP transistor such as **2N2907A** could be used.

Howerver, the only pnp transitor that I have is **A928A.**
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/KSA928A-59269.pdf

Do you think this PNP transistor could work ? I am a beginner so I don't really understand the difference between all those different transistor...

Comment: Why do they recommend a transistor anyway? It seems to be a 5V ttl uart line... a 5V arduino could handle that fine directly.

Comment: well in fact they say that sometime the TX line of the robot isn't powerfull enough to drive the RX of the arduino.... Do you think I need this if I use a "software serial" ?

Comment: That wouldn't be true. A high impedance input is about the same as a transistor. There is also no pull up (assuming internally enabled on arduino rx?). The only time a transistor should be needed is if the TX is lower than 5V, closer to 3.3v. Then the transistor is used as a level shifter. I don't know enough about the robot to answer more. It just seems weird.

Comment: in fact I'm trying to drive a Romba robot, here is a link if you wish to learn more (there also another link inside the pdf...) http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_to_5V_Logic.pdf, since I will use a software serial, I think I don't even need a transistor

Comment: I agree with @Passerby. You have a 5V TTL serial port, you should be able to connect the Arduino serial port directly. [Spec here](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf?la=en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the justification for the pnp transistor:

> Note that Serial1(TX1/RX1) should be used on the Arduino Mega. The serial port output TXD from the Roomba/Create is too weak to drive the RX serial port (Serial0) input of an Arduino properly. This is because of the USB-Serial converter on the Arduino: it also tries to drive the RX serial port input via a pullup resistor, but the Roomba does not have enough drive to pull the RX down below about 2.5 volts, which is insufficient to be reliably detected as a TTL serial input of 0. Furthermore, using Serial1 still allows for the use of the Arduino Serial Monitor for debugging purposes. Also note that Serial2 or Serial3 could be used if selected in software.

This may be out of date, as AFAIK the Rev 3 uno has the hardware serial TX RX resistors on the side between the usb and atmega, so anything connected to the TX RX pins have precedence.

software serial libraries won't have this problem.

You should be able to connect it directly. If it doesn't work, then try the pnp transistor. As the current being switched is incredibly small, any small pnp transistor should work. ***Make sure you wire it correctly, as the pin out of the transistors are not the same***.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the robot circuitry, I'd say yeah, give it a try. The A28 doesn't have quite the gain or voltage capacity of the 2N4403, but that's probably not an issue here. Match the pins correctly, then Plug it in and see what happens.